# Validating Angular form with PrimeNG and Material components

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material, primeng

I have an Angular6 form with a mix of Material and PrimeNG components.
Using  for Material errors display, and that works fine.
But in PrimeNG6 there is no such tag AFAIK.

Using PrimeNG Combobox (Autocomplete variant) and Month Picker (Calendar variant).  On the form using FormGroup and FormBuilder.
All fields are required, any errors have to be displayed only when user clicks on Submit.
How can that be achieved?
(as of now I see "required field" errors right away, not on Submit)

I noticed [ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}" form option,
but getting an error on form load:
Can't bind to 'ngFormOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'form'...

Should that error msg div be wrapped into another conditional div?
What condition?

Another complication is a group of Material Checkboxes,
not a simple validation (but hope to handle it when finding an answer 
to the previous question).

Please help!

TIA,
Oleg.

Comment: It seems that ngFormOptions is not working in 6.1.4, so I put updateOn at the end of that formBuilder:this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            category: this.category,
      ...
    }, {updateOn: 'submit'});

Comment: It seems that ngFormOptions is not working in 6.1.4, so I put updateOn at the end of that formBuilder:      this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            category: this.category,
      ...
    }, {updateOn: 'submit'});     where   category = new FormControl('', Validators.required);          but my error msg still shows on load or doesn't show at all even on submit.   <div class="error" [hidden]="!form.hasError('required', 'category')" style="color: red">Field is required</div>          so on which condition should I wrap it  in, If (form.submitted) ?

Comment: And it seems updateOn / FormBuilder fix was not back ported on 6.1.3 yet:  https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/24599